# what happens if open fails?

Tags: perl, ipc

I came across the following code:

```
my $pid = open (my $handler, "-|");
unless ($pid) 
{
    #child stuff
    exec $command;
}
else
{
    #parent stuff
}
```

what would happen if the implicit fork fails? will the command be executed anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the command will be executed, unless the code uses something like [autodie](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autodie).

`open($fh, '-|')` returns `undef` on failure, which is false, so the (unforked) process would exec the command (and thus terminate itself).

(On an unrelated note, I, and many other programmers, feel that `unless ... else ...` is bad style, but it *is* valid Perl.)